# Bulk operation has failed in Couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchnode

I'm new in Couchbase.
I'm trying to some basic operations with Node.js from the [Couchbase Documents](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/bulk-operations.html) on Couchbase Server 3.0.1 .
When I try the bulk operations, the codes - that have gotten from Couchbase docs - has failed.

There is a Data Bucket named "test". And the bucket has 2 records they have doc number 1 and 2. I can success if I get the documents one by one.

But the following codes return an error such as;

> throw new TypeError('First argument needs to be a string or buffer.');

My codes;

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('192.168.170.129:8091');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('test');

// Bulk operation

bucket.get(['1', '2'], function(err, res) {

  if(err) {
    console.log("one or more operation failed", err);
    return;
  }

  console.log("success!", res);

});
```

**Edited:** I'm using Couchbase Node.js 2.0

Comment: Which version of the Couchbase Node.js SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Couchbase Node.js 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Couchbase Node.js 2.0.0 [API documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.0.0/) the [`get()`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.0.0/Bucket.html#get) only operates on a single key.

The function you are looking for is [`getMulti()`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.0.0/Bucket.html#getMulti):

```
bucket.getmulti(['1', '2'], function(err, res) {

  if(err) {
    console.log("one or more operation failed", err);
    return;
  }

  console.log("success!", res);

});
```